# Explanation of why this closure returns the value at the time of the iteration

Tags: javascript, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

I understand that one issues people have with closures is that it returns the lastest value for a given variable unless you do this:

```
function f() {
    var a = [];
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = (function (x) {
            return function () {
                return x;
            }
        })(i);
    }
    return a;
}
}
```

There is a little too much going on there that I need explained.

Comment: Please be specific on your questions. You should have known that by now.

Comment: It seems like you added a `}` too many.

Comment: check out this question for a good explanation of how closures work in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: @Blankman: You may find it easier to comprehend if you replace the IIFE `(function (x) { return func... })(i);` with a *named* function that is called in the loop: `for(i=0...){some_func(i);}`. Then `some_func` would receive `i`, defined as parameter `x`, and return a function that references `x`. `function some_func( x ) { return function(){ return x; }; }`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the scope of a variable is always a `function` (or the global object). So, if you do something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    a[i] = function (x) {
        return i;
    };
}
```

there is only ONE `i` involved. After the `for` loop finishes, the value of `i` is `2`, no matter which of the `a[i]` functions is called.

To work around this, we need to establish a new scope. Usually this is done by invoking an anonymous function like so:

```
a[i] = (function (x) { // (1)
    return function () { //  (2)
        return x;
    };
})(i);
```

Now the `i` at iteration time is mapped to a brand new `x` for each iteration, and the function (1) makes sure it gets "trapped" until `a[i]` (2) is executed.